# What alternative should use instead of accessing _value directly from Animated.Value?

Tags: react-native

Just noticed on `PanResponder` [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) sample uses  `_value` directly, but this in typescript is not possible because the type is missing that prop, so what other approach should we follow ?, was thinking to cast to `any` but is not a good practice, not sure if I'm missing something, I'm new to native:

```
onPanResponderGrant: () => {
    pan.setOffset({
        x: pan.x._value,
        y: pan.y._value
    });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the _value key is supposed to be private and therefore not reflected in the AnimatedValue type in typescript.

As a workaround I found the following to be working:

Inside the `onPanResponderRelease` callback, instead of using `pan.flattenOffset()` – `pan.extractOffset()` works as well and you won't have to use `pan.setOffset()` anymore.

```
const panResponder = useRef(
  PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
      Animated.event(
        [null, { dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y }],
        { useNativeDriver: false }
      )(e, gestureState)
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: () => pan.extractOffset()
  })
).current
```

---

If you are still interested in accessing the value, you can use the provided `pan.addListener()` like this

```
pan.addListener(value => {
  console.log(value)
})
```